# Azure: Writing files into Azure buse queue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

One of my ADF flow create JSON output files in ADLS. I need to write these files as soon as it's available in ADLS to azure bus service queue. Thinking building a azure function app which continousely reading the files and writing into queue.

Could you guide me the best option please.

Can change flow to write into blob if the queue can't read from ADLS or suggest me if there is any other best option.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Data Factory read the from ADLS directly not Service Bus.  Data Factory access the data through linked service, then copy the data from linked service 1 source dataset to sink dataset in another linked service. Did you use data flow to create the json  file or how did get the JSON file, from REST API/Web active?

Answer (score 1):

> Can change flow to write into blob if the queue can't read from ADLS
> or suggest me if there is any other best option.

If you use blob trigger of azure function, then you can read the file as a blob item instead of read it as ADLS item.